# adding values of two columns in different databases sql

Tags: sql

I have two tables Product and Stock that sit on two different databases, dbA and dbB respectively. They contain QTY, Quantity columns respectively.

```
QTY  Quantity
---  -----
50    30
50    40 
50    60
50    50
```

I want to return the sum of all the values in these two columns. 50 + 50 + .. 40 + 60 + 50 = 380

If I do this: `SELECT sum(QTY) FROM dbA.Product` I get 200  and `SELECT sum(Quantity) FROM dbB.Stock` gives me 180 but when I do something like this:

`SELECT sum(QTY) + sum(Quantity) FROM dbA.Product, dbB.Stock;` I don't get 380 but some other number which I have no idea how it arrives to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are doing a cross join.

Do this instead:

```
select coalesce(asum, 0) + coalesce(bsum, 0) 
from (select sum(qty) as asum from dba.Product) a cross join
     (select sum(quantity) as bsum from dbB.Stock) b
```

The cross join is producing every possible pair of values between the two tables for a total of 16 rows (4*4 = 16)  For each row in the first table you are getting the rows:  (50, 30), (50, 40), (50, 60), (50, 50).

Comment: thanks that did it! yeah that's what i thought at first... i need to refresh my knowledge on joins! thanks for the added explanation! :)

Answer (score 0):

this works too:

```
SELECT
     x.total + y.total AS total
FROM
     (SELECT
         SUM(quantity) AS total
      FROM
         dbB.stock) AS x
CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT
         SUM(qty) AS total
      FROM
         dbA.product) AS y
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to sum two subqueries instead of cross join

```
SELECT (
        SELECT SUM(QTY)
        FROM dba.Product
        ) +
       (
        SELECT SUM(Quantity)
        FROM dbB.Stock
        ) AS Total
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fe930/1)